# CoreData context issue - manipulating data under a different context

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm building this project with a ViewModel that creates a new context -> checks to see if the current object exists or is new -> then publishes the any changes to the object,  and saves to Coredata.

My problem is that when I add relationships, I get an error that they are in two different context(s), and I cannot find a place to use any of the addTo(_:) Coredata generated functions. Trying to add a PersonEntity to an OrgEntity

Any Suggestions?

```
struct OrgEntityDetailView: View {

//Bringing in the provider instance
var provider = ContactsProvider.instance

//bringing in org property
//The ObservedObject is going to make sure that the DetailView is reevaluated and rerendered (if necessary), when the budget category changes.
@ObservedObject var orgEntity: OrgEntity

@State private var personToEdit: PersonEntity?

//sheet code
//@State private var sheetToggle: Bool = false

//Fetching and assigning to orgEntity(s)  variable
//@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ) private var personEntitys

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            // Pill shaped picture
            Image(systemName: "building.2")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding()
            
            // Account details
            Text(orgEntity.name)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding()
            
            HStack {
                Text(orgEntity.address)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(orgEntity.city), \(orgEntity.zipCode)")
            }
            .padding()
            
            Divider()
            
            // Contacts list
            Text("People and Todo")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
            
            List {
                Section("Contacts") {
                    ForEach(orgEntity.peopleArray) { person in
                        NavigationLink {
                            PersonEntityDetailView()
                        } label: {
                            PersonListRow(personEntity: person)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                Section("Tasks") {
                    ForEach(1...2, id: \.self) { task in
                        Text("Task \(task)")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button {
                        personToEdit = .empty(context: provider.newContext)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.title2)
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $personToEdit, onDismiss: {
                personToEdit = nil
            }, content: { person in     //passing in this closure to the view
                NavigationStack {
                    CreatePersonView(vm: .init(provider: provider, personEntity: person))
                }
                
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

### ViewModel

```
class EditPersonViewModel: ObservableObject {
// Create a new context in memory - away from main context - So thay we can add/edit
// then from there decide if we want to merge them in the main context or discard

//Published property of Org type that the app can listen too
@Published var personEntity: PersonEntity

//Insert a new context into this Object - apart from the main context
private let context: NSManagedObjectContext

//constant to differentiate between new or existing org
let isNew: Bool

//create an init that lets us choose from editing an existing org or creating a new one
// Takes 2 parameters, one for the provider and another for a Org, optional so that if its nil well create a new org
init(provider: ContactsProvider, personEntity: PersonEntity? = nil) {
    //set context to new background context
    self.context = provider.newContext
    if let personEntity,   //unwerapping the contact from init funcion if its there
       let existingPersonCopy =  try? context.existingObject(with: personEntity.objectID) as? PersonEntity {
        //checking to see if it exists in coredata - if yes, then load the init with the existing data
        // as? converts to orgEntity data type
        self.personEntity = existingPersonCopy
        self.isNew = false
    } else {
        //create a new OrgEntity in this class for @pub property
        //Using the initalizer with the brand new context just created line above
        self.personEntity = PersonEntity(context: self.context)
        self.isNew = true
    }
}

//function to save/persist/merge our new context, throws incase theres and error with coreData
func save() throws {
    //check to see if there in fact any changes - no point to save if there isnt
    if context.hasChanges {
        try context.save()
    }
}
```

}

### OrgEntity Model:

```
    final class OrgEntity: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var city: String
    @NSManaged var address: String
    @NSManaged var phoneNumber: String
    @NSManaged var zipCode: String
    @NSManaged var people: NSSet?
    
    //used to set default properties
    override func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()
        setPrimitiveValue("", forKey: "phoneNumber")
        
    }
    
}

//Grouping our fetch requests in model under an extension
extension OrgEntity {
    
    //Private so you can use dot notation
    private static var orgEntityFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<OrgEntity> {
        NSFetchRequest(entityName: "OrgEntity")
    }
    
    //this fucntion then used or orgEntityFetchRequest to sort value ascending, etc
    //also returns the array used by Main views 
    static func all() -> NSFetchRequest<OrgEntity> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<OrgEntity> = orgEntityFetchRequest
        //passing in array of sort descriptors
        request.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \OrgEntity.name, ascending: true)
        ]
        return request
    }
    
    //return empty org
    static func empty(context: NSManagedObjectContext = ContactsProvider.instance.viewContext) -> OrgEntity {
        return OrgEntity(context: context)
    }
    
    // Wrapper that returns array to get around coredata NSSet for relationships
    
//    public var personArray: [PersonEntity] {
//        let peopleSet = people as? Set<PersonEntity> ?? []
//        return peopleSet
//    }
    public var peopleArray: [PersonEntity] {
        guard let people = people else { return [] }
        return people.compactMap { $0 as? PersonEntity }
    }
    
    // Accessors
    @objc(addPeopleObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToPeople(_ value: PersonEntity)

    @objc(removePeopleObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromPeople(_ value: PersonEntity)

    @objc(addPeople:)
    @NSManaged public func addToPeople(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removePeople:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromPeople(_ values: NSSet)
    
}

//extension for Previews and generating them
extension OrgEntity {
    
    //function that returns array of orgEntitys - takes in count of how many to make and what context to use - all static so no instance needed
    @discardableResult
    static func makeOrgEntity(count: Int, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [OrgEntity] {
        var orgs = [OrgEntity]()
        for i in 0...count {
            let org = OrgEntity(context: context)
            org.name = "Name \(i)"
            org.address = "\(i) Michigan St"
            org.city = "Aurora \(i)"
            org.phoneNumber = "\(i)-999-9999"
            org.zipCode = "0000\(i)"
            
            orgs.append(org)
        }
        return orgs
    }
    
    //return a single contact - uses subscript [0] instead of .first
    static func preview(context: NSManagedObjectContext = ContactsProvider.instance.viewContext) -> OrgEntity {
        return makeOrgEntity(count: 1, in: context)[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s hard to read the code with all the comments but it doesn’t look like you are copying orgEntity to the child context which is needed if you’re going to use it in a relationship

Comment: Yes - Sorry about the comments. Are you talking about bringing in orgEntity as a property in to the ViewModel?

Comment: Well the context property is in the view model so something like that.